# Как получить Token в Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь делать все в точности как в документации Framework

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

Внутри models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Но всегда получаю

```
  {
  "username": [
    "This field is required."
  ],
  "password": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

[image: Postman window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно передавать информацию в body запроса. Например: 
{"username": "Werton", "password": "xpto"}

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь с данным `username` должен существовать.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ответу сервера, view по какой-то причине не видит ваши переданные поля (если возвращается ошибка This field is required, то значит соответсвующие поля в полученных данные пустые). Посмотрите какой запрос приходит на сервер, что в теле запроса.